# What causes a bool to output a random number?

Tags: c++, boolean, undefined-behavior

I am working on my game, and in the implementation I have these chunks of code from various locations of the project. I am checking if the variable `isCreated` is false, to draw it to the GUI, but instead, the cosnole outputs a random number somewhere in the 100s (recent attempts display 104 and 120). Is there something in the code that is causing an address issue? I have no idea how something like this could happen when the boolean is declared.

Note: `InputMenuPtr` is a smart pointer to `InputMenuGUI`.

EDIT: `isCreated` outputs as 0 until I get to consistency test #3...

ANOTHER EDIT: Here is the code that proves the setter function is in-fact being used.

```
InputMenuGUI testMenuGUI("custom"); //create object

InputMenuGUI(std::string s){setter(s);}; // calls this constructor

void setter(std::string s){ myStyle=s;
            isCreated=false;isClean=false;isActive=false;}

//this is the setter function.
```

Out of the original...

```
struct InputMenuGUI{
        InputMenu *myMenu;
        ScrImage iMenu, tMenu;
        Sprite sMenu[3];
        Paragraph pMenu;
        Coord2 pos;///Pos is Top Mid of Menu Border
        bool isCreated, isClean, isActive;
        std::string myStyle;
        Button clickRange;
        std::map<int, ScrImage> screenMap;
        std::map<int, Sprite> spriteMap;
        std::map<int, Paragraph> textMap;
        std::map<int, Button> buttonMap;
        ///--------------------------------------------
        InputMenuGUI(){setter("custom");};
        InputMenuGUI(std::string s){setter(s);};
        void setter(std::string s){ myStyle=s;
            isCreated=false;isClean=false;isActive=false;}
        void display(Gorilla::Silverback *gameSB, Ogre::Viewport *gameVP, Coord2 anchorT);///->

        }

void GameApp::startInputMenu(){
        {///Escape Menu (Testing Phase)
            //Create menu, add params
            InputMenu testMenu("Really Exit?");
            testMenu.addButton(ChoiceButton("Please!",1,10));
            testMenu.addButton(ChoiceButton("I'm kiddin!",2,12));
            //create menu's gui, link ptr of menu, set menu gui ptr in map
            InputMenuGUI testMenuGUI("custom");
            std::cout<<"testing: " << testMenuGUI.isCreated << std::endl;
            testMenuGUI.myMenu=&testMenu;
            std::cout<<"testing2: " << testMenuGUI.isCreated << std::endl;
            appMenu["ExitMenu"].reset(&testMenuGUI);
            printf("Testing Consistency #%d: %d\n", 1, testMenuGUI.isCreated);
            printf("Testing Consistency #%d: %d\n", 2, appMenu["ExitMenu"]->isCreated);
        }
        ///start the input menus for GUI
    }

void GameApp::loopInput(){
    if(myKeyboard->isKeyDown(OIS::KC_ESCAPE)){
                std::cout<< "Pushing menu"<<std::endl;
                printf("Testing Consistency #%d: %d\n", 5, appMenu["ExitMenu"]->isCreated);
                myGUI.pushMenu(appMenu["ExitMenu"]);
            }
{

void GameUI::pushMenu(InputMenuPtr i){
        Coord2 tAnchor((*myGameAnchor)["T"]);
        tAnchor.add(0,(*myGameAnchor)["B"].y/4);
        printf("Testing Consistency #%d: %d\n", 4, i->isCreated);
        ///Note: when changing res, update menu positions
        ///ToDo: Movable menus. if you hold the mouse button down, have notes on the last pos to make a relative movement
        activeMenus.push_back(i);
        printf("Testing Consistency #%d: %d\n", 3, i->isCreated);
        i->display(myGameSB,myGameVP,tAnchor);
        std::cout<<"Menu pushed"<<std::endl;
    }

void InputMenuGUI::display(Gorilla::Silverback *gameSB, Ogre::Viewport *gameVP, Coord2 anchorT){
        std::cout<<"testing created: "<<isCreated<<std::endl;
        if(!isCreated){

        //...
        }
```

Comment: Voted to close as lacking example. The relevant code is not shown.

Comment: A debugger would be most helpful.

Comment: Short answer: memory corruption/undefined behavior somewhere in the code that's not shown here.

Comment: This is all the code regarding the object, there isn't anything else to add besides the entire source file of InputMenuGUI (which is over 100 lines long)

Answer (score 1):

`isCreated` is most certainly uninitialized. In that case it's value is usually whatever is currently at its memory location.

Comment: When I construct the object, it immediately goes to the `setter()` variable, which makes `isCreated=false;` I do this all the time, how does it not work here?

Comment: @Molma In your example you are not calling your setter before printing the member. Also, initialization should always take place. Write proper constructors!

Comment: I edited the post to display the exact lines that prove the setter function is being used.